# How to Set SubView Size Same as Navigation bar Size?

Tags: ios, subview

Here I have created Navigation bar with height 50 and width as view size.Now, I want to add a subview in the navigation bar with same navigation bar size.How to set the frame size for subview?

ViewController.m

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
   UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
   [self.view addSubview:navbar];
}
```

Comment: UIView* subview = [[UIView alloc] initinitWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
  [navbar addsubview:subview];                                                                           If i put like this,its not working...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code won't respond to the orientation changes (portrait / landscape handling) nor support split screen. To fix it, instead of setting frame in `viewDidLoad` (where btw you do not call `super`!) write:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    [self.navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
}
```

Then as it is a different view, you should create a subclass of your view. The code will work in a way as @raghu wrote, but it won't be easily maintanable and will be of low quality. Separate of concerns!

Inside your `UIView` subclass you should implement `init` methods and `layoutSubviews` where you should set a proper frame.

Comment: @raghu You leave it where you've written it. Ideally you should keep it elsewhere, but atm don't mind it. Anyway, you keep the initialization in your viewDidLoad (but call super) and save it as property. Then in viewWillLayoutSubviews you can access this property.